# Mixed Content Laravel API Endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nginx

My VueJS/Laravel site is running https by default but somehow there is an endpoint that when called is still on http instead of https. This project wasn't developed by me and I have limited knowledge on Laravel. Nginx configuration seems to be fine, where would the issue be most probably? I'm not sure where to start looking. Somehow this app is able to run without having to use `URL::forceScheme('https');` and again nginx seems to be good (since by default the site is already on https). Most parts of the api call https save to just **one URL**. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application are using vue components? If yes, so check into the components where the ajax is sending the URL and check if it is setting the URL endpoint with http.
Is recommended to set the URL endpoint domain variable into a .env file and call the URL endpoint domain variable into the URL endpoint param on ajax method.
On this way you has no risk of send a different URL endpoint.

Comment: I actually found the answer already but I wasn't able to update this. You are correct though, the previous developer implemented the ajax call differently and inefficiently by calling windows.location which was annoying to say the least.